# How can I use a for loop in this class to make passing input more efficient?

Tags: python, loops, object

I am a little confused on how I can use a loop so I can eliminate the 9 individual set calls. I am not sure why my existing for loop is failing. I also tried using a return statement before the three statements contained within. Ideally I would like to understand how I can utilize the employeeList as well and have the for loop step through employeeList while passing information into the set methods. Please explain.  Apologies if the terminology I am using is incorrect I am still trying to get the hang of objects.

```
class Employee: 
        
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        self.__name = name  
        self.__age = age
        self.__salary = salary
            
    def setEmployeeName(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def setEmployeeAge(self, age):
        self.__age = age
        
    def setEmployeeSalary(self, salary):
        self.__salary = salary
    
    def config(self):
        print(self.__name, self.__age, self.__salary)
        
    def getFull(self):
        return self.__name, self.__salary, self.__age
        
        
emp1 = Employee(None, 0, 0)
emp2 = Employee(None, 0, 0)
emp3 = Employee(None, 0, 0)

# employeeList = [emp1, emp2, emp3]

emp1.setEmployeeName(input("input employee 1's name:"))
emp1.setEmployeeSalary(input("Input employee 1's salary: "))
emp1.setEmployeeAge(input("Input employee 1's age: "))

emp2.setEmployeeName(input("input employee 2's name:"))
emp2.setEmployeeSalary(input("Input employee 2's salary: "))
emp2.setEmployeeAge(input("Input employee 2's age: "))

emp3.setEmployeeName(input("input employee 3's name:"))
emp3.setEmployeeSalary(input("Input employee 3's salary: "))
emp3.setEmployeeAge(input("Input employee 3's age: "))

 for emp1 in employeeList:
     setEmployeeName('Bob')
     setEmployeeAge(23)
     setEmployeeSalary(345)
    
print('',emp1.getFull(),'\n', emp2.getFull(),'\n',emp3.getFull())
```

Comment: You can iterate from 0 to 2 using a for loop. Ask user input and save it in the ith index of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list of employees using a for loop.

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__salary = salary

    def setEmployeeName(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def setEmployeeAge(self, age):
        self.__age = age

    def setEmployeeSalary(self, salary):
        self.__salary = salary

    def config(self):
        print(self.__name, self.__age, self.__salary)

    def getFull(self):
        return self.__name, self.__salary, self.__age

    def __repr__(self):
        return ','.join(self.getFull())


employeeList = []

for i in range(3):
    emp = Employee(None, 0, 0)
    emp.setEmployeeName(input(f"Input employee {i + 1}'s name:"))
    emp.setEmployeeSalary(input(f"Input employee {i + 1}'s salary: "))
    emp.setEmployeeAge(input(f"Input employee {i + 1}'s age: "))
    employeeList.append(emp)

print('\n'.join(map(str, employeeList)))
```

---

I added an implementation for [**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) so that you can just map employees directly to strings without calling .getFull(). You could use a loop instead if you prefer the tuple notation.

```py
def __repr__(self):
    return ','.join(self.getFull())
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate method and explanation on repr.I am always seeking alternatives to my code so I can learn new techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is failing because you aren't calling any method on the object.
The line:

```py
for emp1 in employeeList:
```

Means "for every object in the employeeList list, assign that object to the variable `emp1` and execute the following code for each object:".  So you could change it to:

```py
for emp1 in employeeList:
  emp1.setEmployeeName("Bob")
```

... etc., but that isn't really going to help since they don't all have a name of "Bob."  So you can do this:

```py
employeeList = []
line = input("input employee name (leave blank to stop):")
while line.strip() != "":
  name = line.strip()
  age = input("input employee age:").strip()
  salary = input("input employee salary:").strip()
  employeeList.append(Employee(name, int(age), float(salary)))
  line = input("input employee name (leave blank to stop):")
```

Or just read the data from a file, e.g. by using the `pandas` module (`pandas.read_csv()` for example).